# XPages SSJS generate a random number within a range

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I've been trying to simple generate a random integer between 1 and 5 (including 1 and 5).
How do I do this using SSJS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return (Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+1)

    }]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```